# Different results between snakemake running a hardcoded command and executing same command from terminal

Tags: parameters, command-line-interface, snakemake

We've got a Snakemake pipeline that yields results that are wrong. After a lot of debugging we narrowed it down to some code which gives a different result in Snakemake as compared to the (correct) output created by directly running the reported command from the terminal.

Initially our command had a bunch of dynamic parameters included. For testing purposes we replaced the dynamic command in Snakemake with the literal code as it is resolved by Snakemake. (We got this using the -p flag.) We still got different results between running that command within the pipeline and in the terminal.

Finally I moved the code to a separate bash file, so execution of the command is never directly on the command line or parsed in any way by Snakemake. The problem persists. The hardcoded command is as follows:

```
java -Xms128M -Xmx180G -cp './ext_tools/SearchGUI-3.3.9/SearchGUI-3.3.9.jar' 'eu.isas.searchgui.cmd.IdentificationParametersCLI' -out './temp_6aug/out/searchgui/BN_n17_lysC_F34/BN_n17_lysC_F34_searchgui.par' -db './temp_6aug/out/seqDB/multiSampleDB_uniqueIDs_concatenated_target_decoy.fasta' -enzyme 'Lys-C' -msgf_fragmentation '2' -frag_tol '0.02' -fi 'c' -ri 'z' -fixed_mods 'Carbamidomethylation of C' -variable_mods 'Oxidation of M'
```

One of the differences we see is that if we run the code from the terminal the **msgf_fragmentation** flag gets processed correctly. But it does not when called by Snakemake. Other aspects of the output file (a parameter file) that aren't even addressed in the above command are different as well.

This problem replicates across runs and on several computers with different operating systems, so differences in environment variables seem unlikely to be the cause. My first instinct was to check for string interpolation and unicode related issues, but I couldn't find anything like that, all relevant files are in plain ASCII.

**EDIT**

Initially we ran Snakemake with the -p flag and tried running the printed command directly in the terminal (which worked). When this static command is pasted into Snakemake it again does not work. We took it one step further and even the following does not work (the sh file contains the same hardcoded command as shown above):

```
rule searchGUIparameters: # create parameter file
    input:
        outputDir + 'seqDB/multiSampleDB_uniqueIDs_concatenated_target_decoy.fasta'
    output:
        outputDir + 'searchgui/{msSample}/{msSample}_searchgui.par'
    params:
        sampleParams = lambda wildcards: ' '.join(config['msSamples'][wildcards.msSample]['searchParams'])
    shell:
        './run_par_creation.sh'
```

As the parameters specified under 'params:' are by now not used in the shell command, we don't think we need to include the config file, as it is no longer used within this rule at all.

Comment: Seeing the snakemake code would be helpful for debugging. Have you tried `--printshellcmds, -p` to see how snakemake resolved the commands?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have clarified my original question.

Comment: Could you also add `rule all` and relevant part of the config file? A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will make it possible/easy to debug.

Comment: Argh, I didn't get any notification when you made the edits. Getting different outputs even after hardcoding everything into bash file is really strange. Snakemake uses bash strict mode; would it be the reason possibly? See [1](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#my-shell-command-fails-with-with-errors-about-an-unbound-variable-what-s-wrong), [2](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#my-shell-command-fails-with-exit-code-0-from-within-a-pipe-what-s-wrong) for info related to that.